# Never stopping gif prealoder

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, gif

Im doing a one page website that is getting quite bulky because of heavy images and animations so I decided to add a preloader.

The simplest thing I found was adding a GIF preloader. The gif shows ok at the beggining but doesnt stop at all and continues going forever.

This es HTML:

```
<body id="page-top" data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar-fixed-top">

    <div class="loader"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.loader {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 9999;
    background: url('../img/716.gif') 50% 50% no-repeat rgb(249,249,249);
}
```

And above the  tag in index.html is this :

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function() {
    $(".loader").fadeOut("slow");
})
</script>
</head>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Page might not be fully loaded. Maybe a 404 on your page somewhere?

Comment: I left it for five minutes and still nothing. Without the gif and all the code loads completely in 8 seconds.

Comment: Sorry... that was my best guess.

Comment: Sorry! You made me realise My jquery the googleapis code was missing htttps:// before the url of jquery.min